# How to launch sample AEM project from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, adobe, osgi, aem

I've downloaded the AEM developer tools from https://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools/ and followed instructions from http://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/dev-tools/aem-eclipse.html to setup a starting project

It looks like this:

[image]

My AEM is running on `localhost:4502`, how can I actually post this sample code in AEM and test it out?

On the bottom left if I right click on server and click Start then I get this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the properties of server. Click on change location to  [workspace metadata]. Clean the server. and Restart. Its working at my end earlier I had the same issue.[image]

Hope this will work
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just start your server by runing cq_location\crx-quickstart\bin\start.bat and follow [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391840/create-a-hello-world-bundle-in-eclipse-and-check-the-working-jar-file-on-crx/28696048#28696048)